# Core Data group NSDate into month/year

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Suppose I have some NSDates in a table:

- 1/11/2012
- 1/16/2012
- 2/14/2012
- 4/13/2012
- 4/14/2012
- 4/18/2012

I would like to group these dates by month and year such that I get:

- 1/2012
- 2/2012
- 4/2012

I currently resort to fetching every record in the table, performing a `valueForKeyPath` on the date column, extracting `NSDateComponents` and storing the results in an `NSSet`.  This seems a bit inefficient.

I would like to know if there is a way to write an NSPredicate that will group these dates on the database side.

Comment: Have you got the solution from this?I am having the same problem now/can u please suggest me what to do.I still didnt understand a thing from the accepted amswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar, and I use an extra attribute in the entity that is named `sortDate`. 
I set the sortDate from my custom date setter.

Something like this:

```
- (NSDate *)monthDateFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    NSDate *monthDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    return monthDate;
}

- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"date"];
    [self setPrimitiveStartDate:date];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"date"];

    NSDate *sortDate = [self monthDateFromDate:date];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"sortDate"];
    [self setPrimitiveSortDate:sortDate];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"sortDate"];
}
```

Comment: So do you define `sortDate` as a transient property in your core data model?

Comment: it's a regular attribute that is saved in the database. I hope that this will make the sectioning faster. From my experience NSDate calculations are pretty expensive. Though I never profiled it, but I'm pretty certain that it's faster to compare sqlite's TIMESTAMP values then to calculate a new NSDate for every object in a fetch.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is the timezone sensitivity. Even if you change timezone and you move the dates several ours to the past/future, the sortDate will remain the same.