# How to fetch record according to months from core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I want to create a bar graph for current year showing selling of this year from core data.On x axis amount is shown and on y axis month are shown and date stored in core data in Date format.I don't know how do I fetch record according to months like january,february,march etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSFetchRequest group by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461460/nsfetchrequest-group-by-month)

Comment: Duplicate of [Core Data group NSDate into month/year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12918017/4244136)